# SQL search issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is a simple question but here it goes.  I've created a search button in Visual Studio using an SQL Statement. It works for first name and last name, but I also want it to search int such employee Id's. Here is the code :

```
SELECT ID, fName, lName, Discription, Box 
FROM tb1 
WHERE (fName LIKE '%' + @fName + '%') OR (lName LIKE '%' + @lName + '%') OR (ID LIKE '%' + @ID + '%')
```

When I test it, I get the error :

```
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of ID comparison you intend to do, but very probably you don't want to cast it to VARCHAR and filter with a LIKE condition. Please check exactly what you want and try to transform your ID filter into a range query, so that it uses your index and becomes much simpler and more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `LIKE` with integers, so you will have to convert the `ID` to `varchar`.

To convert you can use `CAST` or `CONVERT`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Ex: 
`CAST(ID as varchar)`

Your query:

```
SELECT ID, fName, lName, Discription, Box 
FROM tb1 
WHERE (fName LIKE '%' + @fName + '%') OR (lName LIKE '%' + @lName + '%') OR (CAST(ID as varchar) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%')
```

Comment: Ah I see that makes more sense.  Sorry for the noob question, Could you provide me with the proper code to convert it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ID LIKE '%' + @ID + '%'
```

`ID` is an integer, `'%' + @ID + '%'` is a string.  It can't really compare.  An integer either is a value or it isn't.  The `%` wildcards wouldn't mean anything to an integer.

I'm *assuming* what you want to do is convert the integer into a string so that you can match substrings of it.  So, for example, searching for "1" would match on any integer which *contains* a "1" (10, 11, 12, 451, etc.).  To do that you should simply need to [convert the integer value to a string value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the `WHERE` clause:

```
(CAST(ID AS varchar(10)) LIKE '%' + @ID + '%'
```

(This assumes that your integer will never be more than 10 characters long.  Adjust that value as necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` syntax is compatible only with character-associated data types. `INT` types do not fall under this category.

**Reference**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx